# Combines two tables without overwriting the col

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I combine **tbl2** with **tbl1** like in the given fashion?
I tried to address this using `coalesce` but it is going for a second argument over the first in case of null values. Any help here would be very useful for me.

**tbl1:**

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------+
|   id  | fname | mname | lname |  age  | addr |     email     | location |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------+
|   1.  |   aa  |   a   |  aaa  |   15  | usa  |  aa@gmail.com |    us    |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------+
|   2.  |   bb  |   b   |  bbb  |   22  |      |  bb@gmail.com |    uk    |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------+
```

**tbl2:**

```
+-------+-------+------+-------+
|   id  |  age  | addr |  zip  |
+-------+-------+------+-------+
|   4.  |   55  |  hk  |  4566 |
+-------+-------+------+-------+
|   6.  |   43  |  ch  |  5444 |
+-------+-------+------+-------+
```

**Desired output:**

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------+
|   id  | fname | mname | lname |  age  | addr |     email     | location |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------+
|   1.  |   aa  |   a   |  aaa  |   15  | usa  |  aa@gmail.com |    us    |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------+
|   2.  |   bb  |   b   |  bbb  |   22  |      |  bb@gmail.com |    uk    |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------+
|   4.  |       |       |       |   55  |  hk  |               |          |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------+
|   6.  |       |       |       |   43  |  ch  |               |          |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------+
```

What I tried (was a bit reluctant to put this out here as I'm not confident about it):

```
select 
    coalesce(t1.id, t2.d) as id, 
    t1.fname, t1.mname,t1.fname...so on,
    coalesce(t1.age, t2.age) as age, 
    coalesce(t1.addr,t2.addr), 
    t1.email, t1.location 
from 
    tbl1 t1 
full join 
    tbl2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Does your id are always different between the two tables?

Comment: not necessarily, there are chances of them being the same.

Comment: > but it is going for second argument over first in case of null values ... is not clear. Can you rephrase it or/and give examples.

Comment: Like if i'm using COALESCE here, it basically goes for the second arg if the first arg is found NULL. So the logic that i had in place was mapping the data incorrectly.

Comment: There is no problem with `coalesce()` for the example data we have. Please update the question to show records where coalesce() will actually cause a problem, including how it behaves now verses how you want things to work.

Comment: > So the logic that i had in place was mapping the data incorrectly. ... versus what you have in mind but still not clear for us ... like @JoelCoehoorn wrote above

Comment: If there could be duplicates, that changes the interpretation of the solution - why not provide sample data that demonstrates the possible values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repolace the missing columns with NULL or empty string and UNION them.

It only must have the same number of columns for the UNION or else you get an error

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tbl1
>     ("id" int, "fname" varchar(2), "mname" varchar(1), "lname" varchar(3), "age" int, "addr" varchar(3), "email" varchar(12), "location" varchar(2))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tbl1
>     ("id", "fname", "mname", "lname", "age", "addr", "email", "location")
> VALUES
>     (1, 'aa', 'a', 'aaa', 15, 'usa', 'aa@gmail.com', 'us'),
>     (2, 'bb', 'b', 'bbb', 22, NULL, 'bb@gmail.com', 'uk')
> GO
> ```

2 rows affected

> 

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tbl2
>     ("id" int, "age" int, "addr" varchar(2), "zip" int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tbl2
>     ("id", "age", "addr", "zip")
> VALUES
>     (4, 55, 'hk', 4566),
>     (6, 43, 'ch', 5444)
> ;
> GO
> ```

2 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT 
> id, fname, mname, lname, age, addr, email, location
> FROM tbl1
> UNION
> SELECT
> id,NULL,NULL,NULL, age, addr, NULL,NULL
> FROM tbl2
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | fname | mname | lname | age | addr | email        | location
> -: | :---- | :---- | :---- | --: | :--- | :----------- | :-------
>  1 | aa    | a     | aaa   |  15 | usa  | aa@gmail.com | us      
>  2 | bb    | b     | bbb   |  22 | null | bb@gmail.com | uk      
>  4 | null  | null  | null  |  55 | hk   | null         | null    
>  6 | null  | null  | null  |  43 | ch   | null         | null
> ```

> ```
> select 
>     coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id, 
>     t1.fname
>     , t1.mname
>     ,t1.fname
>     , t1.lname
>     ,coalesce(t1.age, t2.age) as age 
>     ,coalesce(t1.addr,t2.addr) 
>     ,t1.email
>     , t1.location 
> from 
>     tbl1 t1 
> FULL OUTER join 
>     tbl2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | fname | mname | fname | lname | age | (No column name) | email        | location
> -: | :---- | :---- | :---- | :---- | --: | :--------------- | :----------- | :-------
>  1 | aa    | a     | aa    | aaa   |  15 | usa              | aa@gmail.com | us      
>  2 | bb    | b     | bb    | bbb   |  22 | null             | bb@gmail.com | uk      
>  4 | null  | null  | null  | null  |  55 | hk               | null         | null    
>  6 | null  | null  | null  | null  |  43 | ch               | null         | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3a6e7fa17087c7bf62e76be590772599)*

Comment: Does not work if id are key since duplicates can exist (see comment in OP)

Comment: Thanks bloke. I'll give it a shot. But sure shot there could be dups in! Would that abrupt the logic?

Comment: hi,@Dri372 of course it works, see example joins works horizonqatlly but ypou need union to combine them vetically

Comment: Hi @nbk I wrote does not work if ... and till now we don't have anwser to this if ... in your example id are different so of course it works.

Comment: please make an example fiddle and link it

Comment: @Dri372  Ok i see what you want.

Comment: Hello @nbk, Will both the queries lead to the same soln? I'm curious why 'COALESCE', per my exp COALESCE picks the non null value..Imagine if id-1 fname-null in tbl1, and id-1 fname-xx in tbl2...here coalesce would pick id-1 and fname-xx, which isn't what i want.So you thoughts on this

Comment: coalesce taje the first Value that is not NULL, so first t1.fage then t2.age in that order. Coalesce works if you want first values from t1 and only if they don't exist the algorithm takes data from td2. combining two tables will need many test runs and checks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE     @Table1 TABLE 
            (id int, fname varchar(20), mname varchar(20), lname varchar(20), age int, addr varchar(20), email varchar(20), location varchar(20));
INSERT INTO @Table1 
    VALUES  
            (1, 'aa',   'a',    'aaa',  15, 'usa',  'aa@gmail.com', 'us')
        ,   (2, 'bb',   'b',    'bbb',  22, ''   ,  'bb@gmail.com', 'uk')
;

DECLARE     @Table2 TABLE 
            (id int, age int, addr varchar(20), zip varchar(20));
INSERT INTO @Table2 
    VALUES  
            (4, 55, 'hk',   4566)
        ,   (6, 43, 'ch',   5444)
;
WITH    IDTable AS
    (
        SELECT  ID  FROM    @Table1 UNION ALL
        SELECT  ID  FROM    @Table2 
    )

SELECT  DISTINCT
        id          =   I.id
    ,   fname       =   T.fname 
    ,   mname       =   T.mname 
    ,   lname       =   T.lname 
    ,   age         =   T.age       
    ,   addr        =   T.addr      
    ,   email       =   T.email 
    ,   location    =   T.location  
FROM    IDTable I
JOIN    @Table1 T   ON  T.ID = I.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT  
        id          =   I.id
    ,   fname       =   ''
    ,   mname       =   ''
    ,   lname       =   ''
    ,   age         =   T.age       
    ,   addr        =   T.addr      
    ,   email       =   ''
    ,   location    =   ''  
FROM    IDTable I
JOIN    @Table2 T   ON  T.ID = I.ID
```